# Image Classification training one Image

Tags: image-classification

I want to proceed with learning about one image.

For example, when training the painting of Mona Lisa, I want to prove that the drawing of Mona Lisa's face with eyebrows is a copy of Mona Lisa.

So, I rotated one Mona Lisa painting and created 1080 data by flipping vertically and horizontally.

I conducted training using TensorFlow and Inception V3 model.
However, my model shows a 99% concurrence rate even when verifying a picture of a normal woman, not the Mona Lisa.

I want to finally get the result of detecting the imitation of various photos, not just the Mona Lisa.

Please let me know a better solution. please.